# What are the first four derivatives of m(s,L) and $\phi(s,u)$

Tags: differential-geometry

Holditch's theorem is an old result on the area generated by a moving chord for closed planar curves. Suppose that a constant length moving chord is allowed to rotate a
full turn with its endpoints always lying in a closed convex planar curve α.
A chosen point in the moving chord at a distance $\textit{a}$ from one end and at a
distance b from the other will describe an inner closed curve, the so-called
Holditch curve $H_{\alpha}$ of $\alpha$. Holditch’s theorem states that the difference between the
areas of both curves is equal to $\pi ab$.
I wanna proof a more generalized Version of this Theorem, but I'm kind of stuck when it comes to the Calculation of some Derivatives...

We have the following setup:

Given a smooth closed regular space curve $\alpha:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$, which is paramerized by arc-length.
Let $L>0$ be the Length of the moving chord, so that retrogade motion can't appear.
The p-Holditch curve can be written as
\begin{align*}
H_{\alpha}(s)=(1-p)\alpha(s)+p\alpha(s)
\end{align*}
, where $f:I\to f(I)$ is the Hoditch function  i.e., the smooth bijective
function such that if $\alpha(s)$ is one endpoint of the chord, then $\alpha(f(s))$ is the
other endpoint. $f$ also depends on $L$. We are writing explicitly the dependence on the length $L$ of the chord by naming it
$f(s,L)$.
Define
\begin{align*}
m(s,L):= f(s,L)-s.
\end{align*}
Define $\phi(s,u)$ as the angle between $t(s)$ and $t(s+u)$.

I wanna proof the following Lemma:

The first four derivatives of $m(s,L)$ with respect to L at $L=0$ are

$m_{L}(s,0)=1$,
$m_{LL}(s,0)=0$,
$m_{LLL}(s,0)=\frac{1}{4}\kappa^2(s)$,
$m_{LLLL}(s,0)=\kappa(s)\kappa'(s)$

and the same of $\phi(s,u)$ at $u=0$

$\phi_{u}(s,0)=\kappa(s)$,
$\phi_{uu}(s,0)=\kappa'(s)$,
$\phi_{uuu}(s,0)=\kappa''(s)-\frac{1}{4}\kappa(s)\tau(s)$,
$\phi_{uuuu}(s,0)=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{ds}(\kappa(s)\tau^2(s))+\kappa'''(s)$,

where $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are the curvature and torsion, respectively, of a curve $\alpha$ with a non vanishing curvature.

I have got the tip that the  asserted values of the derivatives in the statement are calculated by successively differentiating the relations $||\alpha(s+m(s,L))-\alpha(s)||^2$ and $cos(\phi(s,u))=\langle t(s),t(s+u)\rangle$ with respect to L and u, respectively.
Furthermore I calculated $m_{L}(s,0)=1$ and $m_{LL}(s,0)=0$ by derivating and using the Rule of l'Hospital. But after that I would need to derivating the following term:
\begin{align*}
m_{LL}(s,L)\langle\alpha'(s+m(s,L)),\alpha(s+m(s,L))-\alpha(s)\rangle+m_L(s,L)^2(\langle \alpha''(s+m(s,L)),\alpha(s+m(s,L))-\alpha(s))\rangle+1)=1
\end{align*}
I am sceptical about the fact that this is only for the third derivative. I guess there might be a smarter solution.

Comment: Do you have an argument that if the original convex curve is smooth (you just said regular, no further assumptions?), then your various functions will be smooth? You've just specified that $f$ is required to be continuous; why should it even be differentiable, let alone smooth?

Comment: @TedShifrin We can assume that the function $f$ is smooth.